# What are known component intelligence tools?

Tags: security, nexus, n3dr

What are available - free and commercial - solutions to create reports about components used in a software project (physically, set of source code repositories), with intelligence on features like security situation and license model of used open source components?

One prominent example is - or was - Nexus Enterprise, but are there other solutions?

An open source monitor that comes to my mind is the Census project for security monitoring:
https://github.com/linuxfoundation/cii-census

**Note**: my impression about Nexus Enterprise is about 2 years old, since then the product name and scope has changed afaik and there are also competitors like Seerene.

Comment: Curious why you said "- or was -" ?

Comment: because my impression about Nexus Enterprise is about 2 years old, since then the product name and scope has changed afaik and there are also competitors like Seerene

Comment: Ah, that might be why they included "Repo Health Check" feature in Nexus OSS then, thanks for the reply.

Comment: [BlackDuck](https://www.blackducksoftware.com/products/protex) has tools to monitor use of open source components, and "manage open source compliance"

Comment: @HuguesM. please post this comment as an answer

Answer (score 2):

<sub>(upon request from comments)</sub>

[BlackDuck](https://www.blackducksoftware.com/products/protex) has tools to monitor use of open source components, and "manage open source compliance & security"